# Oracle SQL Query for retrieving only 2 values among many values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as shown below:

```
amount      debit      credit
------      -----      ------
500         500        
500                    500
550         550        
655                    655
756         756
```

.
.
.
.
.

Now, the question is: How can I retrieve those duplicate values only in the Amount column to display in the screen without using the following:

IN (list)
or anything like this

Comment: I have read the question three times and didn't understand what excactly you want. Can you rephrase the question and post the desired result as well?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger same here... I am still trying to figure out what is required....

Answer (score 2):

You will need to supply the table name in this query

```
select amount, count(amount)
from table_name_here
group by amount
having count (amount) > 1;
```

Comment: Follow-up question: what if the syntax you gave me is used as a sub-query, is that possible...??? Example: SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE (sub-query here)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT (AMOUNT)
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is roughly understandable, so it seems you are looking for result from the following SQL:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM TABLEX
GROUP BY AMOUNT
HAVING COUNT(AMOUNT) > 1;
```

I try to guess from your comment you are looking for result from below SQL:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  TABLEX TBLX1,
 (
  SELECT 
    AMOUNT 
  FROM 
    TABLEX 
  GROUP BY 
    AMOUNT 
  HAVING COUNT(AMOUNT) > 1
 ) TBLX2
WHERE 
  TBLX1.AMOUNT = TBLX2.AMOUNT
```

Comment: This is what I want... Thanks for this one... Follow-up question: is this can be used as a sub-query???

Comment: You can see the expected result on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4f86/11)